# Basic calculator input validation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, validation, parsing, input, calculator

Im trying to improve my Java calculator by being able to validate the input.
My calculator can handle +,-,*,/,^ and ofc ().
I am trying to figure out the best way to validate an input is valid.

A valid input looks like this:

```
10 + 2 + 2 * ( 5 + 6 )
```

An invalid input looks like this:

```
10 $ 2 + 2 * ( 5 + 6 )
```

or

```
5 + 6 + (7 * )
```

You got the idea.

Comment: Well, good luck with that :) - was there a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple, standard algorithm for both checking the syntax of the input and optionally evaluating the expression is Dijkstra's [shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm), which was specifically designed to evaluate expressions like these. It can also be optionally modified to support syntax checking.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a parsing algorithm. I recommend one of two approaches: regex or tokenizing.

Regex would be the most streamlined approach, java has plenty of Regex libraries. You can form a regular expression (Regex) to match valid calculator input. Off the top of my head I can't provide you with a good regular expression, but I'm sure a Google search would provide you with at least a start. The Regex pattern can validate calculator input, essentially performing the parsing algorithm for you.

Tokenizing the input using a string tokenizer (assuming string input) would require a parsing algorithm. Essentially you would algorithmically form a grammar and check a token sequence to match the grammar. For example:

Num -> operator|paren -> num -> ......etcetera

I recommend using a stack to track even parentheses. Every time you encounter a paren either push or pop a placeholder onto/from the stack. An empty stack at the end of the input means even parens. Left paren: push placeholder; right paren: pop placeholder.